# How to fetch the values from Json response?

Tags: python, arrays, json

```
input= [‘{“msg":"result","id":"cloudLogin","result":{"success":true,"data":{"_id":"rD63Disv58oYXRHx7","userName”:”user..net”,”loginTime":{"$date":1592550961780},"clientLocalTime"1591687526276,"offsetTimeZone":-330,"userId”:”123456”,”orgId":"7583”}}’]
```

I want to get the `_id` and `orgId` values in above Json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted isn't valid JSON (funny quote marks, missing colon after `clientLocalTime`).

Saying that, you can convert that string -- after correcting it -- to a Python `dict` using the `json` module. (I have re-formatted the string as multiline for sanity whilst trying to correct it.)

```py
import json

input= ["""
{
    "msg":"result",
    "id":"cloudLogin",
    "result":{
        "success":true,
        "data": {
            "_id":"rD63Disv58oYXRHx7",
            "userName":"user..net",
            "loginTime":{
                "$date":1592550961780
            },
            "clientLocalTime": 1591687526276,
            "offsetTimeZone":-330,
            "userId":"123456",
            "orgId":"7583"
        }
    }
}
"""
]

# load as a python dictionary
as_dict = json.loads(input[0])
print(as_dict['result']['data']['_id'])
print(as_dict['result']['data']['orgId'])
```

gives

```
rD63Disv58oYXRHx7
7583
```